# parallel implementation in R and update values at each time step

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I need your suggestions for correctly implementing the following scenario in parallel, if possible.

Suppose I have a system of ODE for solving some problem. Lets say we have three ODE such that

```
dx/dt = ax+by+cz,  dy/dt = a(x+y)-(b+c)z,  dz/dt = a/b*(xy)+c*z
```

where a, b and c are nonzero parameters. We can solve above system with ode(....) of deSolve package. My problem starts from here.

I want to simulate above system with 20 different initial conditions (i.e 20 such systems run in parallel) such that after each time step (dt=0.001), I need to subtract 0.01(x,y,z) of (i+1)th and (i-1)th systems from the solution of i-th system at that time, i.e values from neighboring system. I can run system in parallel, but I don't know how to update systems after each time step? I also don't know, how to use ode(....) method for only one point of time.

I don't know how to add math equations here. Please guide me as well.

Comment: I don't know about `ode`, but I have serious doubts that you can implement this in pure R. Plus, your updates have to be asynchronous, right? Because otherwise, the i-th system depends on the values from (i-1) and (i+1), but (i-1) also depends on ((i-1)+1) which ends up being i. You might be able to pull it off with something like `RcppParallel`, but it would be *far* from trivial.

Comment: Hard to help you without any code to start with. What did you try??

Comment: Alexis, you are very close to what I am expecting to do. The only update is, to calculate the solution for t_j time first I will update all systems with values from t_(j-1). and yes all systems are dependent on each other.

Comment: If you can figure out how to get the result for a single time-step (or someone else knows how to) and you post the code, then we could better assess if what you want is possible.

Comment: yes, I am trying to find out results for single time step and also waiting reply from someone to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Lotka-Volterra model as an example for each time step but the following two codes are not producing similar results. The error between them is increasing. I don't know why? Also there is a big difference in time to  complete code-2, which is expected but the question is, can we improve?

```
#Original code
library(deSolve); library(lattice)
predpreyLV<-function(t,y,p){
  N<-y[1]
  P<-y[2]

  with(as.list(p),{
    dNdt<- r*N*(1-(N/1000))-a*P*N
    dPdt<- -b*P+f*P*N
    return(list(c(dNdt,dPdt)))
  })
}

r<-0.5; a<-0.01; f<-0.01; b<-0.2;

p<-c(r=r,a=a, b=b, f=f)
y0<-c(N=25, P=5)
times<-seq(0,1000,0.1)
LV.out<-ode(y=y0,times,predpreyLV, p)
```

**Here is code for each time step.**

```
#Code-2, Calculations for each time step
library(deSolve); library(lattice)

predpreyLV<-function(t,y,p){
  N<-y[1]
  P<-y[2]

  with(as.list(p),{
    dNdt<- r*N*(1-(N/1000))-a*P*N
    dPdt<- -b*P+f*P*N
    return(list(c(dNdt,dPdt)))
  })
}

r<-0.5; a<-0.01; f<-0.01; b<-0.2;

p<-c(r=r,a=a, b=b, f=f)
y0<-c(N=25, P=5)
dt<-0.1
LV.out1<-c(0,25, 5)
for (i in seq(0,1000-dt,dt)){
  times<-seq(i,i+dt,dt)
  out1<-ode(y=y0,times,predpreyLV, p)
  LV.out1<-rbind(LV.out1,out1[2,])
  y0<-c(N=out1[2,2], P=out1[2,3])
  out1<-NULL
}
```